# What can go wrong with this code (type-punning)?

Tags: c++, casting, alignment, type-conversion, type-punning

I have implemented this convenience method which both works and looks like it has literally zero overhead when enabling O1 optimizations:

```
template<typename To, typename From>
inline const To& binary_cast(const From &in) {
    static_assert(sizeof(To) == sizeof(From),
                  "Incompatible size.");
    static_assert(std::alignment_of<From>() % std::alignment_of<To>() == 0,
                  "Incompatible type alignment.");
    static_assert(std::alignment_of<From*>() % std::alignment_of<To*>() == 0,
                  "Incompatible pointer alignment.");
    return *(reinterpret_cast<const To*>(&in));
}
```

**Edit: I made the alignment check more lenient, after Hans Olsson's observation.**

I've read about strange bugs that can appear when doing type punning, and for the most part I understand how and why they can happen, but I've never seen such error in practice.

The reasons why I would want to do this are irrelevant, but I'm asking both for practical and academic reasons.

My questions are:

- Are the static assertions I made good enough to make this "safe" and "predictable" for all cases where type punning makes sense?
- Can this possibly still break under different optimization settings, and if so, is there a way to avoid it?
- Will this work with rvalues as well?
- Is this the only way to achieve a similar result other than using
  unions?

Thanks!

Comment: Type punning is an issue usually in the same scope only, where two pointers (or references) point to the same memory with different types. Then the behavior is undefined whenever you try use them in some useful manner. If you perform your cast solely to bass it to a lower level function its okay.

Comment: Your rules are too strict. If you have something with 4-byte alignment you can cast it to 2-byte alignment - but not the other way.

Comment: @Hans Olsson thanks, I hadn't considered that possibility. I updated my snippet with a more lenient check.